# How are transactions counted in Corda toward the 10k free limit?

Tags: transactions, corda, fee, notary

I can't find any documentation on what counts as a transaction and whose count it increases when a notary signs a transaction. Does only the initiating node have its transaction count increased? Or is it all nodes that participated in the flow? Does it matter if you're sending or receiving? Or is it per input since each input has a notary assigned (though I know it has to be the same one)? Or per output?

Comment: I chatted with the sales team and they couldn't give me straight answers either. Waiting on some follow up material.

Answer (score -1):

Corda does not have any limitation on the counts of notarizing transactions. Corda is a free open source software. Notarization that happens in the network does not charges the participating node any fees.

However, if you are referring anything regarding Corda Enterprise evaluation, please reach out to sales@r3.com as pricing is different case by case.

Comment: Its quite clear from his question that he is asking about Corda Enterprise. What isn't clear is how Corda Enterprise pricing actually works. Having different pricing in every case is suspicious business practice too.